# How to print (all) the result(s) of a while loop in reverse order?

Tags: python, while-loop

```
#decimalToBinary

num=int(input("Enter number"))

while num!=0:
    bin=num%2
    num=num//2
    print(bin,end=" ")
```

Let's say the input,here, is 13. It'll give the output:1 0 1 1.
How can I print it in reverse (i.e, 1 1 0 1) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build the whole result in a string, then reverse it :

```
num = 13
bin = ""
while num!=0:
    bin += str(num%2) + " "
    num=num//2

bin = bin.strip();

print(bin[::-1])
```

Outputs :

> 1 1 0 1

Answer (score 3):

Store it in a list, then print it in reverse.

```
#decimalToBinary

num=int(input("Enter number"))
output = []
while num!=0:
    bin=num%2
    num=num//2
    output.append(bin)

print (output[::-1])
```

To print the results as a string

```
print (' '.join([str(o) for o in output[::-1]]))
```

**EDIT**
As suggested in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56240436/how-to-print-all-the-results-of-a-while-loop-in-reverse-order#comment99168233_56240513), Here is the approach avoiding lists.

```
#decimalToBinary

num=int(input("Enter number"))
output = ''
while num!=0:
    bin=num%2
    num=num//2
    output = str(bin) + output

print (output)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. The output now is: [1, 1, 0, 1] . Any suggestions for how to remove the comma(s)?

Comment: use `print (''.join([str(o) for o in output[::-1]]))`

Comment: @DivynshSrivstv . Thanks, it works. There's a shorter version of it though:

Comment: @DivynshSrivstv .Replacing  `output=[]` with `output=''` ; `output.append(bin)` with `output=str(bin)+output` and the final statement(s) with `print(output)`.

Comment: @The_L0s3r. Updated my answer. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Without resorting to some more difficult tricks trying to manipulate where you print things in a console, it might be easier to build up a string in the loop:

```
num=int(input("Enter number"))
digits = []
while num!=0:
    bin=num%2
    num=num//2
    digits.append(bin)
```

and reverse it afterwards:

```
print(digits[::-1]) #this will possibly need formatting.
```

To format this with spaces try:

```
print(" ".join(str(x) for x in L[::-1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

for your example this should work:

```
num=int(input("Enter number"))
lst=list()
while num!=0:
    bin=num%2
    num=num//2
    lst.append(bin)

print(lst,lst[::-1])
```

output:

```
Enter number13
[1, 0, 1, 1] [1, 1, 0, 1]
```

Comment: This is an exact replica of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could append the values of **bin** in an array or just make **bin** an array and append to it and then print the array in reverse.

```
from __future__ import print_function
num=int(input("Enter number"))
bin = []
while num!=0: 
    bin.append(num%2) 
    num=num//2
print(*bin[::-1], sep=' ')
```